# I can't delete the user logged in with apple

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

We are implementing the new [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12m75xbj) imposed by Apple on user deletion. I am using firebase for auth. I am creating a user account. no problem here. but I can't delete users logged in with apple. i am getting error. I am using this api to delete, [token revoke API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens).
I'm new to swift. I couldn't find the problem

this is my login code. it's working correct :

```
class SignUpNewUser: NSObject {
    /// apple
    var currentNonce: String? // fileprivate
}

extension SignUpNewUser : ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding{
    
    func Apple() {
        let nonce = randomNonceString()
        currentNonce = nonce
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
        
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
    
    private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
        let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
        let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
        let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
            return String(format: "%02x", $0)
        }.joined()
        
        return hashString
    }
    
    private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
        precondition(length > 0)
        let charset: Array<Character> =
            Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
        var result = ""
        var remainingLength = length
        
        while remainingLength > 0 {
            let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
                var random: UInt8 = 0
                let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
                if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                    fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
                }
                return random
            }
            randoms.forEach { random in
                if length == 0 {
                    return
                }
                
                if random < charset.count {
                    result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                    remainingLength -= 1
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}



extension SignUpNewUser: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        
        guard let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential else {
            dataSource?.endSignUpWithError(error: eLogin.authorizationNotFound.error(), method: .apple)
            return
        }
        
        guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
            fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
        }
        
        // JWT
        guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
            dataSource?.endSignUpWithError(error: eLogin.identityToken.error(), method: .apple)
            return
        }
        
        guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
            mylog(eLogin.serializeToken.error(), appleIDToken.debugDescription)
            dataSource?.endSignUpWithError(error: eLogin.serializeToken.error(), method: .apple)
            return
        }
        
        let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce)
        
        @AppStorage("JWt_client_secret") var client_secret: String = ""
        @AppStorage("apltoken") var apple_token: String = ""
        client_secret = nonce
        apple_token = idTokenString

        signInFirebaseAccount(credential, appleIDCredential:appleIDCredential)
    }
    
    
    
    /// signup tamam firebase bağla hesabı
    private func signInFirebaseAccount(_ credential: AuthCredential, appleIDCredential: ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                self.dataSource?.endSignUpWithError(error: error , method: .apple)
            }else{
                guard let user = authResult?.user else {
                    self.dataSource?.endSignUpWithError(error: eLogin.kayitHatasi.error(), method: .apple)
                    return
                }

                // JWT
                guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                    print("hata 5")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                    print("hata 6")
                    return
                }
                guard let nonce = self.currentNonce else {
                    fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                }

                @AppStorage("JWt_client_secret") var client_secret: String = ""
                @AppStorage("apltoken") var apple_token: String = ""
                client_secret = nonce
                apple_token = idTokenString

                
                self.createNewUser(user: user, method: .apple)
                
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i am using this code to delete account. this is not working. I'm adding the console image I got after running the code.

```
extension SignUpNewUser{
    func deleteAppleAccount() {
        @AppStorage("JWt_client_secret") var client_secret: String = ""
        @AppStorage("apltoken") var apple_token: String = ""


        let urlString = "https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

        let paramString: [String : Any] = [
            "client_id": "com.MyCompany.Name",
            "client_secret": client_secret,
            "token": apple_token
        ]

        
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:paramString, options: [.prettyPrinted])
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
//                request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
                guard
                    let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    error == nil
                else {                                                               // check for fundamental networking error
                    print("error", error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
                    return
                }
                
                guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                    return
                }

                
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }else{
                print("deleted accont")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

console output:

```
statusCode should be 2xx, but is 400
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2815e5e00> { URL: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-store"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        26
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 28 May 2022 12:07:51 GMT"
    );
    Pragma =     (
        "no-cache"
    );
    Server =     (
        Apple
    );
} }
```

where am i going wrong? I couldn't find any tutorial about it. Account deletion option will be mandatory after the 30th of the month. I need to fix this now :(

Comment: You should read the last part of the second link you posted... JWT/client secret

Comment: May be missing token_type_hint in your request

Comment: The documentation states client_secret has to be generated based on a key.  This seems to be the disconnect with users who used Sign In with Apple in the app.  Apple only seems to think Sign in is done on the web.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't refresh token users you should try this...

```
let paramString: [String : Any] = [
            "client_id": "com.MyCompany.Name",
            "client_secret": client_secret,
            "token": apple_token,
            "token_type_hint": "access_token"
        ]
```

And if you do

```
let paramString: [String : Any] = [
            "client_id": "com.MyCompany.Name",
            "client_secret": client_secret,
            "token": apple_token,
            "token_type_hint": apple_typeToken

        ]
```

where apple_typeToken could be "access_token" or "refresh_token"

And you should edit your request.httpMethod like

[HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method)

Comment: it turned out very well. status code 200 now returns. but in phone settings it says my app still uses apple id. Am I reading client_secret or apple_token from the wrong place? And I couldn't find where to get the refresh token :( ?

Comment: I don't think this POST request will remove your app's reference from the Apple ID passwords & security section. The user must do that themself. This POST request is only to revoke an auth token. Think of it as a separate issue entirely. It dissociates the authenticity of the login... Firebase has an auth token that does something similair

Comment: Yah, I get a 200 but on credentialRevokedNotification is never fired.  It's the client_secret I think that's the problem here.

Comment: The type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not json

Comment: @ursan526 the client secret isn’t read it is built and signed. Something that shouldn’t be done on device. Look at the link you have in your question.

Comment: @ursan526 can you please help me out to make revoke token request?